# iBooks for OS X cannot scroll div using mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, ibooks, epub3

I'm building an epub for iBooks. The xhtml files in this epub contain a popup with scrollable content. This is only a div inside another div with overflow: scroll. As expected, this works in a web browser, and in iBooks for iPad too.

The problem is in iBooks for OS X (Mavericks). This version of iBooks seems not to listen to 'mousewheel' events in javascript. At first, it doesn't even display the scrollbars. I could make the scrollbars appear with css, and the content can now be scrolled using the visible scrollbar. It just doesn't want to scroll with the mouse wheel. Also, attaching a onmousewheel event with javascript doesn't work either.

I have to use Mootools, so no jQuery solution works for this case.

Comment: do you get any error, or nothing happens? can you reproduce that on a jsfiddle?

Comment: Nothing happens. It is as simple as a div inside another div with overflow: hidden, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/6nHhj/ -- Although, jsfiddle doesn't emulate iBooks for OS X Mavericks.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a Mac issue, check this (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106174/how-to-enable-continuous-scrolling-in-ibooks-1-0-for-osx-mavericks), make a post on that site, and DO come back if you still think this is a Mootools issue.

Comment: Nobody said it's a Mootools issue :) but there could be a workaround. And yes, it can be a Mac/iBooks bug.

Comment: Did you get more info about this? just curious...